# Gradient descent orthogonal steps

Tags: optimization, vectors, matrix-equations, orthogonality, gradient-descent

For the steepest descent algorithm it's stated that

Since $\alpha_k$ minimizes $\alpha\mapsto f(x_k + \alpha p_k)$ it follows
$$
\nabla f(x_k + \alpha_k p_k)^Tp_k=0.
$$

where $p_k = -\nabla f(x_k)$.

I don't see why this is true though. So my question is; why is $\nabla f(x_k + \alpha_k p_k)^Tp_k=0$

## edit

For this question consider $f = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - xb$, then $\nabla f = Ax - b$

And

$$
\alpha_k = \frac{ g_k^T g_k }{g_k^T A g_k}
$$

where

$$
g_k = \nabla f
$$

Comment: @orange this is just a general case, should I put something specific? It could be considered in the context of $f = (1/2)x^TAx - xb$ though, so $\nabla f = Ax - b$

Comment: @orange i thought $\alpha_k$ is just the step size

Comment: @orange well I guess I don't see how I would write that out and reason it, and perhaps that is the crux of this question, I'm not too sure

Comment: Previously  you stated that $\alpha_k$ was an extremum

Comment: @orange $\alpha_k$ minimises $f$ in a particular direction though, it doesn't mean that at the end of a particular path $f$ will be zero? That's only once we get to the minimiser $x^*$, but there could be several steps (and $\alpha$'s) prior to that

Answer (score 1):

Define $$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\quad f_{p,x}(\alpha)=f(x+\alpha p)=\frac{1}{2}\langle A(x+\alpha b),x+\alpha p\rangle-\langle b,x+\alpha p\rangle$$

You can easily calculate $$f'(\alpha)=\langle Ax-b,p\rangle +\alpha \langle Ap,p\rangle $$

Setting $f'(\alpha)=0$ gives you the extremum $$\alpha=\frac{\langle b-Ax,p\rangle}{\langle Ap,p\rangle}$$

Differetiating again:
$$f''(\alpha)=\langle Ap,p\rangle >0$$
since $A$ is positive definite and $p\neq 0$. So $\alpha$ is a global minimum.

In the method of steepest decent we use the direction $-\nabla f$ with
$$\nabla f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)x-b=Ax-b=:r.$$
We call $r$ the residue.

If $x$ is optimal with respect to the search direction $p$ then for $\phi(\alpha)=f(x+\alpha p)$ we have
$$\phi(0)=\min_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}\phi(\alpha) \Rightarrow \phi'(0)=0.$$
And $$\phi'(\alpha)=\langle \nabla f(x+\alpha p),p\rangle=\langle A(x+\alpha p)-b,p\rangle.$$
Since $\phi'(0)=0$
$$\langle Ax-b,p\rangle=0 ´\iff \langle r,p\rangle=0.$$